# Haskell Data Structure not loading

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types

I am trying to set up a data structure that is an extension of lambda calculus to allow addition and subtraction. I am trying to create a structure called AE that can either have a Lit as itself, or evaluate addition and subtraction. The error I am getting says that the following:

Invalid type signature: Lit :: ...

Should be of form variable :: type

Lit :: Int -> AE

What is wrong with my declartion of this data structure?

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}
data AE where
Lit :: Int -> AE
Add :: Int -> Int ->  AE
Sub :: Int -> Int ->  AE

deriving (Show)


eval  ::  AE ->  Maybe Int
eval (Lit n) = Just n
eval (Add n1 n2) = n1 + n2
eval (Sub n1 n2) = do
                      if(n1<n2) then return nothing
                      else return n1 - n2
```

Comment: This AST lacks recursion, so it is very weak: an AE can only be an int, or an addition or subtraction of two ints. You cannot represent 1+2+3, for example.

Answer (score 5):

You need to *indent* the data constructors under the `where` clause, so:

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data AE where
    Lit :: Int -> AE
    Add :: Int -> Int -> AE
    Sub :: Int -> Int -> AE
```

otherwise, you are defining a type `AE` *without* any data constructors. If it is indented, then it is part of the `data AE where` block, and you thus define three data constructors.

Your `eval` function also contains a `do` block. Although `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`, you can not use `do` notation like that. Especially the `return nothing` part is problematic here. For the `Monad` instance `Maybe`, `return = Just`, so that means that `return Nothing` would construct a `Maybe (Maybe a)`. You can work with *guards* to define conditions when a guard should "fire".

Another problem is `n1 + n2`. This has type `Int`, not `Maybe Int`, so you need to wrap it into a `Just` data constructor:

```
eval :: AE ->  Maybe Int
eval (Lit n) = Just n
eval (Add n1 n2) = Just (n1 + n2)
eval (Sub n1 n2)
    | n1 < n2 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (n1 - n2)
```